# Why is one ternary statement cancelling out another?

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-operator

I'm trying to build a set of traffic lights and am currently working on the automated functionality. When I comment out the (sec >= 54) statement, the rest of the program functions as expected - a smooth transition from green to orange to red and back again.

However, with the 'orange flash' (sec >= 54) statement active, the (sec >= 26) statement doesn't work.

```
let time = new Date();
let sec = time.getSeconds();
const defaultSystem = setInterval(dispSecs, 1000);
function dispSecs() {
    console.log(sec++);
    sec === 60 ? sec = 0 : sec;
    sec < 26 ? greenLight.style.backgroundColor = 'green' : 
            greenLight.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    sec >= 26 && sec < 29 ? orangeLight.style.backgroundColor = 'orange' :
            orangeLight.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    sec >= 29 && sec < 54 ? redLight.style.backgroundColor = 'red' :
            redLight.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    sec >= 54 && sec % 2 === 0 ? orangeLight.style.backgroundColor = 'orange' :
            orangeLight.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
```

I have tried to contain the 'orange flash' statement in a while loop. I've looked for spelling errors and I have tried commenting out different parts of the code. I have also tried rearranging parts of the code but this just causes different issues. Even with the 'orange flash' statement operational, the other lights function as intended. I'm just not getting the still orange between seconds 26 and 29. Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing shameful about using plain `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, I have managed to figure out the solution.

```
let time = new Date();
let sec = time.getSeconds();
const defaultSystem = setInterval(dispSecs, 1000);
function dispSecs() {
console.log(sec++);
sec === 60 ? sec = 0 : sec;
sec < 26 ? greenLight.style.backgroundColor = 'green' : 
        greenLight.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
sec >= 26 && sec < 29 ? orangeLight.style.backgroundColor = 'orange' :
        orangeLight.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
sec >= 29 && sec < 54 ? redLight.style.backgroundColor = 'red' :
        redLight.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
sec >= 54 && sec % 2 === 0 ? orangeLight.style.backgroundColor = 'orange' :
        sec;
}
```

It is my understanding that by creating the 'orange flash' rule, I have caused the orange light to remain black at any time outside of (sec >= 54). I think this is due to the last part of that ternary statement. For some reason, this third argument overrode everything else in the program related to the orange light.

Comment: Each of your ternary things is like a separate if/else statement for each range, when what you need is a big if/else if/ else block with a single block of code for each range.